# Accessing php variables in blade file

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I understand that PHP variables passed to the blade file can be accessed using the following syntax.

I have several questions about this

1. What does {{ }} do that allows me to access the variable?
2. Why is it when I am referring to the variable from within the
   element and as text i have to include '' for the former and not the
   latter
3. What does {!!} mean when accessing the variable in javascript
4. Give that $user is an object, why cant i access it via {{$user.id}}
   and I have to use the bracket notation?

Thanks for the clarification guys!

Html Portion

If being access within the HTML element

```
<div id='{{$user['id]}}'>
```

If being accessed as the text for the HTML element

```
<p> {{$user['id']}} </p>
```

In Javascript

```
{ !! $user['id'] !! }}
```

Comment: `!!` means https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: Blade templates are a markup language that is compiled and converted to pure PHP. When the blade engine sees `{{ $someValue }}` It converts it to `echo $someValue` in the pure PHP version.

Comment: Your `$user` object is cast to an Array or implements ArrayAccess so you are able to access it's properties using array syntax. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: "What does {{ }} do" - isn't that part of every tutorial for Blade templates? Also, as you haven't shared any JS code, how is this even related to Javascript? Keep in mind that Blade itself does not know anything about Javascript or HTML, it's just a pure templating engine that can produce all kinds of output. This output needs to be proper HTML or JS code to be interpreted correctly by your browser

Answer (score 0):

1. The syntax **{{}}** is translated as echo in blade.
2. I don't understand very well, but I guess you mean to add a concatenated text string to the variable, no. This works for that, although it is not appropriate to put it inside **{{}}**, since inside the blade you can use it as a normal text string. This works for that, although it is not appropriate to put it inside **{{}}** since inside the blade you can use it as a normal text string.
3. With **{!!! !!}** you make that blade interprets the html elements of the variable as an **html**, what does this mean? that if in the variable **$x** you have a **strong tag**, for example, with **{!!! !!}** you will have the text as strong.
4. The **user.id** syntax is for javascript objects. For Laravel it would be **{{ $user->id }}**